# DSolve for Differetial Equations returns integral

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose that a certain population satisfies the initial value
problem
$$
\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt = r(t) y − k,\quad y(0) = y_0,
$$
where the growth rate $ r(t) $ is given by $ r(t) = (1 + \sin t)/5 $, and $ k $
represents the rate of predation.

1. Suppose that $ k = 1/5 $. Plot $ y $ versus $ t $ for several values
   of $ y_0 \in [1/2, 1]$;
2. Estimate the critical initial population $ y_\text{c} $ below which the
   population will become extinct;
3. Choose other values of $ k $ and find the corresponding $ y_\text{c} $ for each one;
4. Use the data you have found in parts 2. and 3. to plot $ y_\text{c} $ versus $ k $.

I'm stuck in 1. I tried

> `solution= DSolve[{y'[t] == (1 + Sin[t])/5 *y[t] - 1/5, y[0] == 1}, y[t], t]`

But I got an expression with an integral and when I try to plot solution, there is nothing in the plot

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the numeric values, `NDSolve` is the better choice:

```
nsol = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == (1 + Sin[t])/5*y[t] - 1/5, y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 2}]
Plot[nsol[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Still, the output of `DSolve` can be used. Your attempt fails because there's an `Inactive` in the solution, so we need to `Activate` it, and we need to replace `Integrate` with `NIntegrate` to make the code fast enough. An illustration for the difference of performance:

```
int = Inactive[Integrate][(-(1/5))*E^((1/5)*Cos[K[1]] - K[1]/5), {K[1], 0, t}] /. t -> 1;

int // Activate // N // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.25185, -0.214906} *)

int /. Integrate -> NIntegrate // Activate // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0068986, -0.214906} *)

int /. Integrate -> (NIntegrate[##, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}] &) // 
  Activate // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0031274, -0.214906} *)
```

So your code can be fixed in the following way:

```
expr = y[t] /. First@solution /. 
  Integrate -> (NIntegrate[##, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}] &)

Plot[expr // Activate, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: When trying to use NDsolve I got this error: NDSolveValue::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument {(y^\[Prime])[t]==-(1/5)+1/5 (1+Sin[t]) y[t],False}.

Comment: @alex You must have mistakenly typed `y[0]=…` somewhere, and your `y` must be black rather than blue now. When coding in _Mathematica_, one should always keep an eye on the coloring of the code. Just `Clear[y]`. BTW, when you mistype `y'[t]=…`, you will need `Clear[Derivative]`.

Comment: It solved the error but now the output of NDSolve is the plot and it is showed in a little size and the output of Plot[nsol[t], {t, 0, 2}] doesnot shot the function

Comment: @alex The output of  `NDSolveValue` is not a little plot, it's an `InterpolatingFunction[…]`, which is capable of numeric calculation. Please check the document for more detail. "the output of Plot[nsol[t], {t, 0, 2}] doesnot shot the function", I'm sorry but I fail to understand this part of your comment.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.